# gwt requestFactory search

Tags: gwt

GWT RequestFactory is nice while saving/update the data, using as below:

```
EmployeeRequest request = requestFactory.employeeRequest();
EmployeeProxy newEmployee = request.create(EmployeeProxy.class);
newEmployee.setName("Joe!");

Request<Void> createReq = request.persist().using(newEmployee);
createReq.fire();
```

and we use remove instead of persist to delete.

Then how about Search using RequestFactory. Say my domain object is Employee with name, login & address. All three fields are optional for search, Can we achieve this using RequestFactory? or we should use RPC?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your example, you can find user with `RequestFactory` like this:

```
request.employeeRequest().find(newEmployee).with("name", "login", "address");
```

Comment: name, login & address are fields of the entity 'Employee'. Could you please elobarate on how this can be done in RequestFactory or Domain. If I'm not wrong, you are passing the three field values of newEmployee.

Comment: you're right, didn't notice `setName()` -- if skipped that line and used the `EmployeeProxy` (e.g. a new [empty] object) you would retrieve one Employee matching any/all of those fields. Thus `request.employeeRequest().find(newEmployee).with(...)` would get you the (singular) employee you requested. On the other hand, if you're searching many than you would implement a `findAny(...)` inside your `RequestContext` interface.

If the entity doesn't work with `find(..)` for some reason, you would need to create a class that implements `Locator`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in several ways, very similar to how you'd do it with GWT-RPC:

- `request.findEmployees(optionalName, optionalLogin, optionalAddress).fire(new Receiver<List<EmployeeProxy>>() { … })`
- `EmployeeSearchProxy search = request.create(EmployeeSearchProxy.class);

  search.setName(optionalName);

  search.setLogin(optionalLogin);

  search.setAddress(optionalAddress);

  request.findEmployees(search).fire(new Receiver<List<EmployeeProxy>>() { … })`